# How to get DOM element properties before they render in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a div in which I am playing a video using a video tag. The problem is before playing the video I am calculating the ratio between the div and video and I am getting undefined if I console the out in the browser console.

```
const App = () => {
const vRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
const dRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
const [videoHeight, setVideoHeight] = useState<number | null>();
const [containerHeight, setContainerHeight] = useState<number | null>();
const [newHeight, setNewHeight] = useState<number | null>();


useEffect(() => {
        const reference = dRef.current;
        if(reference){
            const oldHeight: number = reference.getBoundingClientRect().height
            setContainerHeight(oldHeight);
            if(containerHeight && videoHeight){
                setNewHeight(containerHeight/videoHeight)
            }
        }
    },[]);


console.log(newHeight);

return <div ref={dRef}>
<video className='video-player' ref={vRef}>
  <source src={"..."} />
</video>
</div>

}
```

I am getting `undefined` on `newHeight`. I need to calculate this ratio before playing the video.

Comment: *"I need to calculate this ratio before video component mounted."* That seems logically impossible. The `video` element doesn't have a height until it's in the DOM and the DOM has been reflowed.

Comment: I mean before playing the video

Comment: videoHeight is `undefined`, the if case never runs. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't getting the height of the `video` element anywhere in that code. (And there are some minor type issues.)

Instead, be sure to get the height of each element, and then do the calculation; see `***` comments:

```typescript
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
    const vRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
    const dRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [videoHeight, setVideoHeight] = useState<number>();           // *** Removed `| null`,
    const [containerHeight, setContainerHeight] = useState<number>();   // *** with no arg `undefined`
    const [newHeight, setNewHeight] = useState<number>();               // *** is automatically added

    useEffect(() => {
        // *** Get the DOM elements
        const div = dRef.current;
        const video = vRef.current;
        if (div && video) { // (this is probably unnecessary in runtime terms, but
                            // it makes TypeScript happy when we use them below)
            // *** Get the height of each of them
            const divHeight = div.getBoundingClientRect().height;
            setContainerHeight(divHeight);
            const videoHeight = video.getBoundingClientRect().height;
            // *** Get the ratio (note: "newHeight" seems an odd thing to call a _ratio_)
            setNewHeight(containerHeight / videoHeight);
        }
    },[]);

    console.log(newHeight);

    return <div ref={dRef}>
        <video className='video-player' ref={vRef}>
            <source src={"..."} />
        </video>
    </div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting a new height because of this `if(containerHeight && videoHeight)`, as you are trying to use `containerHeight` and `videoHeight` as “truthy” before `React` has re-rendered.

You could do so with fewer states:

```
const App = () => {
  const vRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const dRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [videoHeight, setVideoHeight] = useState<number | null>();
  const [containerHeight, setContainerHeight] = useState<number | null>();
  const [newHeight, setNewHeight] = useState<number | null>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const divHeight = dRef.current?.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    const videoHight = vRef.current?.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    setNewHeight(divHeight / videoHight);
  }, []);
  console.log(newHeight);

  return (
    <div ref={dRef}>
      <video className="video-player" ref={vRef}>
        <source src={"..."} />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Also note that TypeScript won't be happy with that use of `.current` without checking whether it's non-`null`.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder, I am gonna add more informations.